# Corrosion of a galvanic couple made with silver and gold

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering, corrosion

If a bangle is made out of gold and silver, connected with each-other would there be a corrosion happening? If so can it be explained using the galvanic series?

Also do those metals undergo oxidation under normal conditions?